# Не переведено сообщение когда перестаёшь отслеживать ответ

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, отслеживание-сообщений

> You’re no longer following this answer
>
> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14438

Ожидается в свежих сборках. Текущая 2020.12.18.38240

Comment: это ваш 600 ответ на мете ruSO

Comment: @Danis прямо как мерседес! Надо свой малиновый пиджак от моли отряхнуть.

Comment: вы единственный человек который занимается переводами?

Comment: @Danis из тех, кто утверждает строки через traducir, похоже, что так. Но переводы делают и другие.

Comment: @Danis btw, если это вы жмёте upvote на комментариях, то это не надо делать просто так. Я раньше (когда только пришёл на SO) думал, что это как-то прилетает в карму автору (по аналогии с голосами на сообщениях), но по сути, нет. Поэтому upvote ставлю либо когда действительно полезная добавка к посту, либо что-то прикольное.

Comment: я это сделал чтобы не писать комментарий по типу "понятно"

Comment: @Danis "понятно" - было бы понятнее :) А так - хз кто там лайки ставит. Ну и "понятно" тоже не обязательно, т.к. это лишний пинг автора - и не все это любят, наверное.

Comment: после этого комментария захотелось написать "понятно" :)

Comment: Не хочу задавать отдельный вопрос поэтому напишет здеаь. Если зайти в "связаться с нами", то там нету перевода кнопки "submit" https://i.stack.imgur.com/z891X.jpg

Comment: @Danis в следующий раз заводите [пункт сразу на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358823/339911).